# How to slice this df dynamically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas df which looks like this. I want to slice it in this way. Every df should start with rate until another rate column shows up. For this I should have 4 slices as Rate is there 4 times. How to do this dynamically?

Here is what the df looks like

[image: df looks]

```
rate_values = df['Rate'].unique()
sub_dfs = [df.groupby('Rate').get_group(r) for r in rate_values] 

print(sub_dfs)
```

Comment: "I want to slice it in this way." In what way ? This question needs to be much more specific and descriptive of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do groupby on columns

```py
sub_dfs = [g for _, g in df.groupby(df.columns.to_series().eq('Rate').cumsum(), axis=1)]
```

```
print(df)

   Rate  15 Days  Rate  15 Days  Rate  15 Days
0     5        1     5        1     5        1
1     6        2     6        2     6        2
2     7        3     7        3     7        3
3     8        4     8        4     8        4
4     9        5     9        5     9        5

from pprint import pprint
pprint(sub_dfs)

[   Rate  15 Days
0     5        1
1     6        2
2     7        3
3     8        4
4     9        5,
    Rate  15 Days
0     5        1
1     6        2
2     7        3
3     8        4
4     9        5,
    Rate  15 Days
0     5        1
1     6        2
2     7        3
3     8        4
4     9        5]
```

Answer (score 0):

First find the indices of the column for which it is equal to `'Rate'`. Then use a loop to create the sub_df's by using `df.iloc[:, ids[i]:ids[i+1]]`. Only for the last sub_df you need to do something different: `df.iloc[:, ids[i]:]`.

```
cols = list(df)
ids = [i for i, j in enumerate(cols) if j == 'Rate']


sub_dfs = [df.iloc[:, ids[i]:ids[i+1]] if i < len(ids)-1 else df.iloc[:, ids[i]:] for i in range(len(ids))]
```